# Create a modal for a card

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page with a series of cards. Each card has a button to open a modal with some options. Which way would be more efficient at serving the modal?

1. Store the HTML of the modal on the page once. Emit an event from each card and load the single modal (passing in any relevant data such as the card id that emitted the event).
2. Have a modal for each card but hide it with `v-if` so it's not rendered. It's unlikely that the modal will be opened often anyway.
3. Something else?

Comment: Is your performance problem actual or hypothetical?  If it's hypothetical, make your code as canonical as possible (i.e. understandable by someone else familiar with Vue), until you *do* have an actual performance problem.  The Vue tutorials and instructional guidance support "best practice" techniques; use them.

Comment: Obviously less is better for performance?

Comment: The third option would be Vuex but that heavily depends on your scenario and if you need the data to be in a global state. If it's just in between the components directly, then I'd go for solution 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's unlikely that there would be significant performance problems with a bunch of cards and dialogs whichever way you go. Both of your proposed solutions would work fine performance wise. This means you could decide based on other very important factors.

I believe **the second solution is preferable because it encapsulates the behavior better**, and does not push the responsibility of displaying the modal dialog to the parent of all cards. It also scales better, because if you had lets say slightly different types of modal dialogs, you would have an option to simply use different dialog component in different cards easily. You would not have to deal with either giving parent even more responsibility (having to decide which dialog component to display), or deal with having one dialog component which would have to do too much because of the need to display different types of contents.

I would also advise you to take a look at the [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue), which would allow you to use your dialogs as part of your cards, and at the same time render them wherever you need in the DOM. For example in the end of the root element of your application (or even in your parent component).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the better way must be something like that:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="card in cards">
      <span>Card: {{ card }} </span>
      <button @click="open(card)">Open</button>
    </div>
    <dialog open v-if="cardSelected">
      CardSelected: {{ cardSelected }}
      <button @click="close">Close</button>
    </dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    cards: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    cardSelected: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    open(card) {
      this.cardSelected = card;
    },
    close() {
      this.cardSelected = null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Maybe the dialog must be a diferente component.

I think that way seems to option 1.